# Feller's probability - A tricky question on birthdays

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stuck, and would like someone to lead me in the right direction.

> Given thirty people, find the probability that among twelve months there are six containing **two** birthdays and six containing **three**.

*Solution.*

I would compute the probability of this event as:

$$p=\frac{{30 \choose 2}{12 \choose 6}6^{2}{28 \choose 3}{6 \choose 6}6^{3}}{12^{30}}$$

Am I counting correctly? My answer doesn't match that given in the text.

Comment: Your denominator $12^{30}$ looks fine, but please explain how you came up with that numerator. I get $$\binom{12}6\binom{30}2\binom{28}2\binom{26}2\binom{24}2\binom{22}2\binom{20}2\binom66\binom{18}3\binom{15}3\binom{12}3\binom93\binom63\binom33$$  $$=\frac{12!}{6!6!}\cdot\frac{30!}{(2!)^6(3!)^6}.$$

Comment: Why don't you tell us the answer in the text, so we don't have to look it up?

Comment: @bof, the answer in the text is precisely what you have written, 

$$\frac{30!}{{2^6}{6^6}}{12\choose6}12^{-30}$$

I am curious to know, why do we keep sampling sequentially 2 people from the group of 30 people until we hit 18, and then sample sequentially in 3's?

Comment: First, in $\binom{12}6$ ways, we decide which months have two birthdays. Say we decide that the first six months of the year have two birthdays. Then, from the $30$ people, we have to decide which two have January birthdays; next, from the $28$ remaining people, which two have February birthdays, and so on.

Comment: @bof, I see the logic now. So, that's how $2(6)+3(6)=30$ birthdays in all. I should have interpreted the problem as - among 12 months there are 6 months that contain 2 birthdays "each" and 6 months containing 3 birthdays "each". 

I counted for only one of $2$ and $3$ birthday months.

Comment: @Quasar - Using stars and bars, number of ways for birthday-month combination is $\binom {30+11}{11}=\binom {42}{11}$. Number of ways of having $6$ months with $2$ birthdays and $6$ months with $3$ birthdays is $\binom {12}6$. Hence probability required is $\binom {12}6\big/\binom {42}{11}$. Why does this not work?

Comment: @hypergeometric, if we had $r=30$ indistinguishable people(balls) to be placed in $n=12$ cells, the number of distinguishable distributions are -

$${{r+n−1}\choose{n−1}}$$

Any distribution can be expressed in the form of occupancy numbers of the cells $1,2,…,12$. The above expression for $\text{# of ways to place r indistinguishable balls in n cells}$ would also include distributions such as $(30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$. These do not satisfy the criteria given in the problem.

Comment: @hypergeomtric, the distinguishable outcomes, taking the people to be indistinguishable, are not all equally likely. "30 in January" is a lot less likely than "2 each Jan-Sept. and, 4 each Oct-Dec." It's these unequally likely outcomes that are counted by stars and bars (given the 30 birthdays are each uniformly and independently distributed among the 12 months).